# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError on email sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have tested the account using my mail client and everything seems to be working fine, but when I try to send through my Rails 4 app I get the error:

> Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [PN1PR01CA0089.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] )

config:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: "smtp.live.com",
port: 587,
domain: Rails.application.secrets.domain_name,
authentication: "login",
enable_starttls_auto: true,

#tls: true,
user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password,
openssl_verify_mode: 'none'}
```